# Show / hide div - using ACF flexible content

Tags: javascript, php, css, advanced-custom-fields

I'd like to show and hide articles like in the image bellow. My code is working to display the first article, but I'd like it to work on all articles.
 The thing IS : I am using ACF flexible content, so I can't find how to "target" articles. 
How can I apply this effect on all article generated through acf flexible content ?[image]

css:

```
.content {display: none;}
```

animation :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).parents('h1').next('.contenu_atelier').fadeToggle(500);              
    });     
});
```

php:

```
if( have_rows('ateliers') ): 
while ( have_rows('ateliers') ) : the_row(); 

if( get_row_layout() == 'atelieratelier' ):


        <div id="Workshop">
             <!-- Buttons -->   
            <h1><button id="toggle" ><?php the_sub_field('atelier_01');?></button></h1>

            <!-- Article to show -->
            <div id="content">
                <p class="some-texte"><?php the_sub_field('my-article-text');?></p> 
            </div>
        </div>



endif;
endwhile;

 else :
endif;
```

Comment: please post a fiddle so we can help you in action

Comment: As @AnasOmar mentioned, please copy your result (html code) to fiddle with JS and CSS, please.

Comment: Thank you, but I solved it bellow ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I changed the structure of the php, and add a javascript effect
(don't forget to load jquery) 
javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
allPanels.slideUp();
$(this).parent().next().slideDown();
return false;
});
$('.accordion > dt > a').eq(0).click()
})(jQuery);
```

php :

```
<div class="accordion">
            <?php

            if( have_rows('ateliers') ):

            while ( have_rows('ateliers') ) : the_row();

            if( get_row_layout() == 'atelieratelier' ):?>

            <dt>
            <a href=""><h3><?php the_sub_field('atelier_01');?></h3></a>
            </dt>

            <dd>
            <?php the_sub_field('my-article-text');?>
            </dd>

            <?php endif;

            endwhile;

            else :

            // no layouts found

            endif;

            ?>
```

css :

```
.accordion-container h3{
color: #ee1c31;
font-weight: 600;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```